# Rewriting an input file to an output file list in differing order efficiently

Tags: python, list, indexing, file-io

So here is a basic look of what I am trying to do.

Take the below file containing numbers such as:

begin_file

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
four,4
five,5
```

Then create a 3rd item in each list with the total from before. Then switch the order to match below.

final_file

```
  1,one,1
  2,two,3
  3,three,6
  4,four,10
  5,five,15
```

How can I  write out the data to the output file as shown, here is what I have below:

```
begin_file = open('in.dat', 'r')
final_file = open('out.dat', 'w')
total = 0
for line in begin_file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if len(line) > 0:
        li = line.split(',')
        total += int(li[1])
        final_file.write(li[1], li[0], str(total))
begin_file.close()
final_file.close()
```

So the exception being raised is that write() or writelines() takes exactly one argument and I'm giving 3.

Is there a way to have the ouput file write in this format? Or am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Thanks for any help everybody!

Comment: "format" is already the right word (and it is a string method).

Comment: So Michael, should I first combine each string, then format to match the desired output?

Comment: "format" allows to combine multiple items (strings and other) into one string. A format string controls how this is done. The combined string can then be written as row to the file.

Comment: your data looks like `CSV` file so you could do it simpler with module `csv` or even `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python library has the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for dealing with files in this format.

If you do need to handle it manually, you'll need to construct a string before writing it to the file, using something like `','.join(li[1], li[0], str(total))` or `'%s,%s,%d' % (li[1], li[0], total)`; however, using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `with` statement to open your input and output streams. This ensures that they are properly closed when you are done with them (when the `with` block ends).

You can use the `print` statement's `file` argument to print to the file:

```py
with open('in.dat') as begin_file, open('out.dat', 'w') as final_file:
    total = 0
    for line in begin_file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line:py
            li = line.split(',')
            total += int(li[1])
            print(li[1], li[0], total, file=final_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin_file = open('in.dat', 'r')
final_file = open('out.dat', 'w')
total = 0
for line in begin_file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if len(line) > 0:
        li = line.split(',')
        total += int(li[1])
        combined = [li[1], li[0], str(total)]
        complete = ', '.join(combined)
        final_file.write(complete + '\n')
begin_file.close()
print(final_file)
final_file.close()
```